# How to add transition to the creation and deletion of a context menu in d3.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, d3.js, transition

I'm creating a [Force-Directed Graph](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) version 6. For every node, when users click on it, a context menu will appear. When users click somewhere else (e.g. click at the SVG), the context menu will disappear. It looks like this:

**No context menu**

[image: No context menu]

**With context menu**

[image: With context menu]

So far, everything works perfectly. Now, I want to add 2 transitions to the creation and deletion of the context menu, which are `d3.easeCircleIn` and `d3.easeCircleOut` (from [d3-ease](https://github.com/d3/d3-ease) library) respectively.

To create the context menu, I create a donut chart with the static data. The code looks like this:

```
// Create context menu data
const contextMenu = [
    {
        value: 1,
        type: 'unlock',
        icon: require('@/assets/images/unlock.svg'),
        text: 'Unlock the node to re-layout the graph'
    },
    {
        value: 1,
        type: 'info',
        icon: require('@/assets/images/info.svg'),
        text: 'Show node detailed information'
    }
];

const pie = d3.pie()
    .value((d: any) => d.value)
    .padAngle(0.0349066); // 2 degrees in radian

this._donutData = pie(contextMenu);

this._arcGenerator = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(this._options.nodeRadius * 1.35)
    .outerRadius(this._options.nodeRadius * 2.5)
```

And then, on the `click` event of a node, I create the donut chart using this function:

```
private createDonut(node: any) {
    const _me = this;

    return node.selectAll('arc')
        .data(this._donutData)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', this._arcClass)
        .attr('d', this._arcGenerator)
        .attr('fill', '#eeeeee')
        .style('opacity', 0.7)
        .on('click', function (event: any, chosenArc: any) {
            
            // Remove other context menu
            d3.select(`.${ _me._contextMenuClass }`).remove();

            // Further processing...

        });
}
```

Now, I want to add [d3-transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) to this creation. I tried to extend the code above by adding `.transition()` to the end (after the `click` event) but it doesn't work.

I did the same with the deletion and it also doesn't work.

```
// Doesn't work
d3.select(`.${ _me._contextMenuClass }`)
    .transition()
    // transition duration and so on...
    .remove();
```

So, what should I do to add the transition to my context menu? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`.transition()` has [its own event system](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on), you can transition towards `opacity: 0` and then `.on("end", function() { d3.select(this).remove(); })` to remove the node only when it's already invisible!